# Why we get Uncaught (in promise) when using default definition of reject but is not the case for resolve?

Tags: javascript

I tried these two code spinets in chrome console:

This code snippet does not through any error:

```
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve ("nicely done!");
});
```

however this one does

```
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  reject ("Whoops!");
});
```

and says Uncaught (in promise) Whoops!

why? why the JS engine treats the defualt definition of reject and resolve differently ?

Comment: That's the whole point of `reject`. When you `reject` it means there was an error in the promise execution. It's equivalent to throwing an error.

Comment: Just add `catch`, and you'll see the error text only without `Uncaught`, if it embarasses you: `let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  reject ("Whoops!");
}).catch(console.error); `

Comment: It's like asking why `return` and `throw` are treated differently.

Answer (score 1):

A rejected promise represents a failed operation resulting in an error: the value with which the promise is rejected, in your case `"Whoops"`. Not handling this promise using either `.then(_, onReject)`, `.catch(onReject)` or `try { await promise; }` basically means that you are ignoring an error, kind of like you'd do for synchronous errors.

Thus the platform must have some way to tell the developer that something went wrong, in node this would terminate the process (although it triggers an event on `process` so you could handle it there as a last resort). For more information in the way, the node platform handles this see https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection.

Of course in the browser terminating the process would mean closing the tab or something so you only get the error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

After rejection anything with error, or without error you should use .catch for handling errors. It should be like bellow

```
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  reject ("Whoops!");
});
.catch((errors) => {
   console.log(errors)
})
```